# Cactus identification

Tags: identification, plant-care, cactus

I live in a student house where one of my fellow housemates has a cactus. She's incredibly bad in caring for her plants and pretty much doesn't give any attention to them whatsoever.

Though, she managed to keep one plant alive. However, that's probably because it's a cactus.
Anyway, enough background information... This cactus suddenly started growing a stem and is starting to bloom (see pictures below). The picture with the stem is quite blurry because we couldn't focus on it.

We wonder if someone here knows what cactus this is and how to best to take care of it. We also wonder if it's normal that it grows a stem this large as we've never seen this.

**Pictures**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not a cactus, possibly a South African succulent called Haworthia. There are a lot of them that look similar. Perhaps a Haworthia expert will happen along.

Comment: Agreed - they are similar to aloes, except for the flowers which are quite different. After it has flowered *don't water it at all for three months* to let it go dormant. The flower spike will gradually dry and shrivel, eventually it will either drop off or be very easy to pull off. Don't attempt to cut it. Keep "neglecting" it the same way, and it should flower every year.

Comment: @alephzero So if I understand correctly, no watering until it goes dormant? After that, should it get watered (if so, how much) or just let it be? We keep it indoor and is pretty much the whole day in the sun, so I imagine that it should get watered a tiny bit.. Anyway, awesome stuff! Thanks for the information (both of you)!